# Find my computer name (Windows 10)

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

How would I find my computer name using the command prompt? I tried the `whoami` command, but that displays my login name. I am looking for the actually network name of my client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the command "hostname" in the command prompt and in a powershell window.

Also in powershell you can you view the environment variable to get the hostname by typing $Env:COMPUTERNAME and hitting enter.

There are other very useful powershell commands at the below URL (if you decide to use powershell)

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/samples/collecting-information-about-computers?view=powershell-6

Answer (score 1):

Open command prompt and type `hostname` and it will display your computer name.